# disable console pop-up for shell script

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, pycharm

When I run a shell script in pycharm/powershell or command window,  eg: `./abc.sh`, then a popup window is open and then shows the status of the execution and closes before I could read it. Making it pointless. A better option would be to show the status right below when I input the command. Or redirect it to a text file. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Run run the command in git bash and it stays in the window itself.